# Prob. 2, Sec. 3.3, in INTRO. TO REAL ANALYSIS by Bartle & Sherbert: What is the limit of this sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, proof-verification

Here is Prob. 2, Sec. 3.3, in the book *Introduction to Real Analysis* by Robert G. Bartle & Donald R. Sherbert, 4th edition:

> Let $x_1 > 1$ and $x_{n+1} \colon= 2 - 1/x_n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $\left( x_n \right)$ is bounded and monotone. Find the limit.

My Attempt:

> We are given that $x_1 > 1$, and 
>   $$ x_{n+1} = 2 - \frac{1}{x_n} \tag{0} $$
>   for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
>
> As $x_1 > 1$, so 
>   $$0 < \frac{1}{x_1} < 1,$$ 
>   which implies that 
>   $$ -1 < - \frac{1}{x_1} < 0, $$ and hence 
>   $$ 1 < 2 - \frac{1}{x_1} < 2,$$ 
>   that is, 
>   $$1 < x_2 < 2. \tag{1} $$
>   Suppose that $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k \geq 2$ and also suppose that 
>   $$ 1 < x_k < 2. $$
>   Then upon taking the reciprocals in the last chain of inequalities, we obtain 
>   $$ \frac{1}{2} < \frac{1}{x_k} < 1, $$
>   and so 
>   $$ - \frac{1}{2} > - \frac{1}{x_k} > -1, $$
>   which implies that 
>   $$ 2 - \frac{1}{2} > 2 - \frac{1}{x_k} > 2-1, $$
>   and hence 
>   $$ \frac{3}{2} > 2 - \frac{1}{x_k} > 1,$$
>   which we can rewrite as 
>   $$ 1 < x_{k+1} < \frac{3}{2} < 2.  $$
>   Thus by the Principle of Mathematical Induction, we can conclude that 
>   $$ 1 < x_n < 2  \tag{2} $$
>   for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \geq 2$.
>
> Moreover, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we also have 
>   $$ x_n - x_{n+1} = x_n - 2 + \frac{1}{x_n} = \left( \sqrt{x_n} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_n} } \right)^2 \geq 0, $$
>   because from (2) it is clear that $x_n$ is a positive real number. Therefore, we can also conclude that 
>   $$ x_n \geq x_{n+1} \tag{3} $$
>   for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
>
> From (2) and (3), we find that our sequence $\left( x_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ is a bounded monotonically decreasing sequence; so this sequence is convergent. Let us put
>   $$ x \colon= \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n. $$
>   Then from (2) we can conclude that 
>   $$ 1 \leq x \leq 2, $$
>   and thence from (0) we obtain 
>   $$ x = 2 - \frac{1}{x}, $$
>   which implies 
>   $$ x^2 -2x + 1 = 0, $$
>   and hence $$x = 1. $$
>   Therefore, we have 
>   $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 1. $$

Is my solution correct? If so, then is every step in it correct and lucid enough too? If not, then where is (are) the issue(s)?